# Check if List<string> exists

Tags: c#, list

This is my code

```
List<string> list = new List<string>() { "bfd", "jy", "aaaaa", "ndnk", "ntfn", "gfm", "gfm", "mhgd5h", "srsr", "ntr", "mtmyt", "dmy", "mmy6", "ngn9d", "y6m1", "d8dm", "bbbbb", "tym", "dmj", "trsh", "tsr"};
List<string> test = new List<string>() {"aaaaa","bbbbb","ccccc","ddddd","eeeee","fffff","ggggg" };
           
foreach (var a in list)
{
    foreach (var i in test)
    {
        if (i.StartsWith(a) == false)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to output from the list and match in the test. If the test exists, then it will not be displayed. If there is no side output，But there may be a problem with my code, it will output the same value many times

The list contains aaaaa, according to logic, aaaaa should not be output

Comment: The code does what you asked it to do. So, take a step back. What **exactly** do you want outputted (the **exact** thing you want outputted)?

Comment: I _suspect_ what you want is `var results = list.Except(test).ToList();`

Comment: Can you give a couple of examples of inputs & their respective outputs you expect to get?

Comment: Sorry, I updated the code

Comment: What **exact** output do you want? Don't tell us what you _don't_ want - tell us **exactly** what you expect the output to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
      List<string> list = new List<string>(){"bfd", "jy", "aaaaa", "ndnk", "ntfn", "gfm", "gfm", "mhgd5h", "srsr", "ntr", "mtmyt", "dmy", "mmy6", "ngn9d", "y6m1", "d8dm", "bbbbb", "tym", "dmj", "trsh", "tsr"};

      List<string> test = new List<string>(){"aaaaa", "bbbbb", "ccccc", "ddddd", "eeeee", "fffff", "ggggg"};

        foreach (var a in list)
        {
            if (!test.Contains(a))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(a);
            }       
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are simple solutions using LINQ. But since I assume this is an exercise, I will show you the detailed version using loops.

The problem is that the `WriteLine` is inside the inner loop. Therefore you will get many repetitions. Store the outcome of the test in a Boolean variable and place the display part after the inner loop.

```
foreach (var a in list)
{
    bool found = false;
    foreach (var i in test)
    {
        if (i.StartsWith(a))
        {
            found = true;
            break; // Exit the inner loop
        }
    }
    if (!found)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(a);  // We must output a here since i out of scope.
    }
}
```

Also, if you want to know whether a specific string is contained in the list, you should probably replace `i.StartsWith(a)` with `i == a`.

---

The code becomes easier to read, if you extract the list search into its own method

```
private bool IsInList(List<string> list, string item)
{
    foreach (string s in list)
    {
        if (s == item)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now, you don't need the Boolean variable any more

```
foreach (var a in list)
{
    if (!IsInList(test, a))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(a);
    }
}
```

I used `!condition` (pronounce: "not condition") instead of `condition == false`. It's terser.

---

I assume that this is an exercise. In production code you would simply use the built in method [Contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.contains?view=netcore-3.1) of the list.

```
foreach (var a in list)
{
    if (!test.Contains(a))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(a);
    }
}
```

or even (as @mjwills suggests in his comment):

```
foreach (var a in list.Except(test)) {
    Console.WriteLine(a);
}
```